# Rails4: production environment create database not using many migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am deploying a rails app to nginx.
There are many migrations in the development stage.

How to create the production schema in a simple way instead of reading many migration.rb files ?

Because I deleted several migration files during develepment. Now when deploy production environment it shows me some errors

Thanks

Comment: It wouldn't take much to convert your schema file into one migration if you wanted to

Comment: Are many of these migrations undoing each other (one migration creates a table, a later migration deletes the table)?

Comment: rake db:schema:load will load your schema.  and then as you make changes you can run migrations from then on.

Comment: @Doon After I do this, can I delete the old migration files ? I want to do this because I deleted several migration files during develepment. Now when deploy production environment it shows me some errors

Comment: When you run the schema:load it will match your schema. to whatever is currently defined in the database/schema.rb, which should be the total of all of your migrations already run in dev environment.   so in theory  you can leave them there as they will not run again when you migrate, since the `schema_migrations` will already have them as being run

Comment: @Doon Thanks, I tried this, error happens `Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]` , I think this is because I did `git mv database.yml database.yml.example` , can I  create a new empty database.yml file to fix this?

Comment: yes, generally speaking as part of your deployment, you need to create a database.yml, since you probably don't want to store your db credentials in source control. I normally do this with linked files in capistrano,(both database.yml and secret.yml), but that is dependent upon your deployment procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the schema.rb file (via rake db:schema:load), but beware it will drop all existing tables. If you have existing data you will lose it.

Once you load the schema then it sets the database version, so only new migrations that are created after the schema file was created will run in the future.

Here is some info for Rails 4.2 about schema dumping:

[Schema Dumping and You](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)